# Issue related to LinkedList reading and writing to .txt file (File content read is not same as written)

Tags: java, string, file-handling, singly-linked-list

I am reading a .txt file in a linkedList, then I am splitting this linkedlist into two equal sized linkedLists.
I am then writing these two (component linkedlists) in two separate files. After saving these files, I need to read these files and get their contents to merge them to form the original data.

But when I read the component files, I have observed that the size of linkedLists is changed from the ones which were written.

For example if my original data_LinkedList had size 402, my two component linkedList had size 201 each, after being written to files and then read again, the size shows to be 208 or 209 for each component. As a result these components do not merge back to form original data.

```
  public class MyFramework {


public static void write(List<String> doublencC, List<String> doubleencR)
{
     String ec="...C Component File Path";

      try {
        FileWriter fileWriter =  new FileWriter(ec);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

       for(String c:doublencC)
       {   bufferedWriter.write(c);
           bufferedWriter.newLine();

       }
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();


     String er="...R Component File Path";
     FileWriter  fileWriter2 =  new FileWriter(er);    
     BufferedWriter  bufferedWriter2 =new BufferedWriter(fileWriter2);
       for(String re : doubleencR){
           bufferedWriter2.write(re);
           bufferedWriter2.newLine();
       }
      bufferedWriter2.flush();
      bufferedWriter2.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error writing to file");

    }

}

public static List <String> [] readFun() throws IOException
{
    String ec="...C Component File Path";
    File D = new File(ec);
   List<String> si = FileUtils.readLines(D);




    String er="...R Component File Path";
    File D1 = new File(er);
   List<String> s2 = FileUtils.readLines(D1);

   List <String> [] myread = new LinkedList [2];
      myread[0]= new LinkedList<String>(si);
      myread[1]= new LinkedList<String>(s2);




  return myread;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File D = new File("...myFile path");

    List<String> data = FileUtils.readLines(D);

List<String> C = new LinkedList <String>(data.subList(0, (data.size()+1)/2));
List<String> R = new LinkedList <String>(data.subList((data.size()+1)/2,data.size()) );
System.out.println(C.size()+" "+R.size());





 System.out.println();
 System.out.println();


 write(C,R);

 List <String> [] myread = new LinkedList [2];
 myread = readFun();

 doubleencC= new LinkedList<String>();
 doubleencR= new LinkedList<String>();

 doubleencC= myread[0];
 doubleencR= myread[1];





  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ReadFile Sizes "+doubleencC.size()+" 
  "+doubleencR.size()+" WrittenFile Sizes "+C.size()+" "+R.size());





     }

   }
```

Comment: Is it possible that some of the strings you are writing out might contain newline (`\n`) characters?

Comment: Why aren't you using Serialization for this? And `flush()` before `close()` is redundant.

Comment: Have you compared the actual data and checked what the differences are?

Comment: @KevinAnderson no, there is no "\n" characters, however, there are general line breaks in the file

Comment: @EJP i have never used Serialization , and even when i do not flush, the error is still the same

Comment: @skw i have not observed much difference, when I print the components and check them written in the files, they are almost the same. However more intended

Comment: What do you mean by "general line breaks"?  Of course there will be the line breaks you specifically inserted with the `newLine()` method. But  if anything you wrote with `write()` has a line break inside of it, that data will look like more than one line when you read it back.

Comment: So I suppose the "almost the same" is the part that is adding extra characters, right? Also, what do you mean by "more intended"? Is it "more indented"? If the latter is the case then try to compare the resulting files with something like WinMerge that also compares non visible characters. I am thinking that probably the problem has to do with character encoding.